# Subscribe PropertyChanged events of window in C++/CLI

Tags: wpf, c++-cli, dependency-properties, visual-c++-2010, propertychanged

I just tried to subscribe to WPF property change events using C++/CLI. I didn't expect this to get difficult.

First I tried to subscribe to a specific property of some window (IsMouseDirectlyOver) and finally succeeded with following code:

```
void MyClass::DependencyPropertyChanged(Object^ sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
   Debug::WriteLine("DependencyPropertyChanged: "+sender->ToString()+", "+args.Property->Name);
}

window->IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged += gcnew DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(this, &MyClass::DependencyPropertyChanged);
```

Then I tried to subscribe to *any* property changes of an object (which is most important to me because my final code must be able to handle property changes by property names). I totally failed on this.

I tried various things but nothing worked. I could not find any C++/CLI examples but according to documentation and C# examples the following seemed to be the most sensible code to me:

```
window->PropertyChanged += gcnew PropertyChangedEventHandler(this, &MyClass::PropertyChanged);

void MyClass::PropertyChanged(Object^ sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs^ args)
{
   ...
}
```

But the compiler tells me by error C2039 that 'PropertyChangedEvent' is no element of 'System::Windows::Window'.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: The WPF Window class simply doesn't implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx), and hence has no PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Do you really want to get notified on *any* property change in a window?

Comment: Yes. But not only of a window. It should also work an any other kind of visual tree object.

Comment: Hmm... no I am not totally right. I need to subscribe to property changes by its *name*. This actually does not mean I need to subsribe to all properties. 
The above mechanism seemed the only one that allowed access by name (using a switch/case by name in the event handler method).
If there is a way to specifically subscribe to one or more properties by name this would solve my probem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look on the snoop sources. I modified it and wrote a very, very basic example that works:

```
String^ ownerPropertyName = "IsActive";
DependencyObject^ propertyOwner = window;

DependencyPropertyDescriptor^ ownerPropertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor::FromName(ownerPropertyName, propertyOwner->GetType(), propertyOwner->GetType());
DependencyProperty^ ownerProperty = ownerPropertyDescriptor->DependencyProperty;
Type^ ownerPropertyType = ownerProperty->PropertyType;

DependencyProperty^ myProperty = DependencyProperty::Register(ownerPropertyName, ownerPropertyType, GetType(), gcnew PropertyMetadata(gcnew PropertyChangedCallback(&MyClass::BoundPropertyChangedCallback)));

Binding^ myPropertyToOwnerPropertyBinding = gcnew Binding(ownerPropertyName);
myPropertyToOwnerPropertyBinding->Mode = BindingMode::OneWay;
myPropertyToOwnerPropertyBinding->Source = propertyOwner;
BindingOperations::SetBinding(this, myProperty, myPropertyToOwnerPropertyBinding);
```

And:

```
static void BoundPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject^ me, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
   Debug::WriteLine("BoundPropertyChangedCallback: "+args.OldValue+", "+args.NewValue+", "+args.Property->Name);
}
```

Looks pretty complicated to me. I have no idea if that binding stuff is really necessary. In fact this can even subscribe to properties that do not have events (like IsMouseOver) and can operate on objects that do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged (like Window). And it does not need any switch/case for properties.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that i have read about this solution in some blog post, but i can't remember where. Anyway it seems to be the right thing to do, at least when Snoop does it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Al mentioned in the comments, your code doesn't work, because there is no `PropertyChanged` event on `Window`, it's as simple as that.

What you can do instead is to override [the `OnPropertyChanged()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onpropertychanged.aspx), which is present on a `Window`. In your override, you can do anything you want, including raising `PropertyChanged` (don't forget to create that event first).

Comment: I can't override a method on the window since the window is a predefined. I can not change it. 

I wonder how a tool like "Snoop" is implemented. It monitors changes of all properties of any kind of WPF object even of windows.
I just tried it out... snoope seems to be able to subscribe to all properties of any kind of object. 

If INotifyPropertyChanged is not implemented by each WPF object, which mechanism does Snoop use?

Comment: @user1421332 Why not simply take a look at [Snoop's sources](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7f9bd00e4559)?

Comment: I will do so. But if I had enough .NET/WPF knowledge to know what I am looking for I probably wouldn't need to ask.

Comment: It seems Snoop uses binding. I never used Bindings before so currently I don't totally understand how it works and if that solves my problem. Oh my, this is really getting complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The class [PropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.aspx) (or the derived [DependencyPropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.DependencyPropertyDescriptor.aspx)) provides a mechanism to add a property change handler by their [AddValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.addvaluechanged.aspx) method:

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor^ propertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor::FromName(
    "ActualWidth", component->GetType(), component->GetType());

propertyDescriptor->AddValueChanged(component, gcnew EventHandler(ActualWidthChanged));
...

static void ActualWidthChanged(Object^ component, EventArgs^ e)
{
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately the handler doesn't get passed the changed property, so i guess you would have to add different handlers for all properties you want to monitor.

---

EDIT: You might implement something like the code shown below that uses an anonymous delegate to pass the property name to an appropriate handler. Note however that this is C#, and to my understanding this can't be done in C++/CLI, since there it does not support managed lambdas. Mayby you could wrap a helper class like this in a separate assembly and use it from your C++/CLI code.

```
public delegate void PropertyChangedHandler(object component, string propertyName);

public static class DependencyPropertyDescriptorExt
{
    public static void AddPropertyChangedHandler(
        this object component, string propertyName, PropertyChangedHandler handler)
    {
        var propertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromName(
            propertyName, component.GetType(), component.GetType());
        propertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(component, (o, e) => handler(o, propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now you could write and use such a PropertyChangedHandler like this:

```
this.AddPropertyChangedHandler("ActualHeight", PropertyChanged);
...

private void PropertyChanged(object component, string propertyName)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works. But as you said, it's a pitty that I can't distinguish the source property. Surely I could add a separate handler for each property but I hoped to avoid the neccessary switch/case orgy (or alike). The ability of the DependencyPropertyDescriptor to be instanciated using property names isn't worth much if the handler doesn't know the origin property too.

Comment: I see a lot of C# code here, the question is C++/CLI.  While translation is straightforward in most cases, you'll need an explicit state object instead of an anonymous delegate -- C++ delegate syntax is not yet usable with .NET.

Comment: Your are right. It always is a hard fight to translate that C# stuff into C++/CLI. But hey... I am really happy about any help even if it involves C# code ;-)

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess you could put the delegate type and the helper class declarations in a separate assembly and reference that from C++.

Comment: @user1421332 Is there any special reason why you bother with C++? Programming WPF would be considerably easier if you'd use C#.

Comment: C++/CLI was my choice because I was a C++ programer all my life. Seemed to be obvious to me. I am also new to .NET/WPF and I tried to keep the entry barrier low. The above syntax is totally new to me. I have no idea how to translate it to C++/CLI.

Comment: I've been programming in C++ for about 15 years and i'm really happy that i could leave it behind. To me C# is a far superior language and i can only recommend to learn it. For WPF it is somewhat like the "natural" programming language. But not only WPF. There is almost nothing you can't do with it.

Comment: I will keep this in mind for my next project. But for my first and current project I need to continue with C++/CLI... including my current problem :-/

Comment: C# is not *superior*, it's optimized to make certain common cases much easier.  But it has nowhere near the power and flexibility of e.g. C++ templates.

Comment: @BenVoigt I said *to me it is superior*. It's just my personal opinion and i don't mind which language you prefer.

Comment: No proposals about the original problem anymore? ;-)

Comment: @user1421332: You can use `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` as this answer suggests.  It just will look different in C++/CLI.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try to understand the C# syntax first. Now I need some sleep :-)

Comment: After reading [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277612/Using-lambdas-Cplusplus-vs-Csharp-vs-Cplusplus-CX) i'm pretty sure that this "anonymous delegate" solution can't easily be done in C++/CLI, since it does not support managed lambdas. You can't use managed types in C++/CLI lambdas, and hence can't use something like a  `PropertyChangedHandler^` in the anonymous method body.

Comment: What a pitty. So I will not twist my mind about that. Anway that bind-to-property solution (see my last answers) seems to solve my problem... if somebody has a better (less complictate) solution please tell me!