# Visual C++ Control Data Binding

Tags: c++, visual-c++, data-binding

Is there a way to Visual C++ Forms to bind a variable from a object to a textbox on the screen? Such as done in C# WPF "Data Source"?

Comment: is this a .net project or a pure win32 project?

Comment: Visual C++ CLR / Win32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, C++/CLI is an [extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) to C++ that allows you to write C++ for .NET.

You can find an introductory explanation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes). It should get you started, and then you should be able to bind things just as you would do in any other .NET language. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002266/subscribe-propertychanged-events-of-window-in-c-cli).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and few samples here

- [How to bind an array of objects to a Windows Form by using Visual C++ .NET or Visual C++ 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815799)
- [Programming Windows Forms with Managed Extensions for C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290064%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [How to: Do DDX/DDV Data Binding with Windows Forms](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/1te0bbs8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)